# Was the Death Star cost effective?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, death-star

According to General Dodonna in the new canonical novelization of *A New Hope*, titled *Star Wars - New Hope:  The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*:

> The Death Star is heavily shielded and carries **firepower greater than half the starfleet’s.**<sup>1</sup>

Let's assume that Dodonna is correct, and the Death Star's firepower is roughly equivalent to that of slightly more than half of the Imperial fleet.  Furthermore, let's ignore the shock value of having this much firepower contained in a single battle station.  Additionally, we will assume that half the Imperial fleet firing on a planet would have the same effect as the Death Star firing on the planet<sup>1</sup>.

We can also speculate that the Empire doesn't want to have to pull half of its existing ships away from their normal duties every time it wants to destroy a planet, so the choice is between building a single Death Star or increasing the fleet's size by just over 50%.

### Which would cost more:  building one Death Star, or building enough Star Destroyers to add something over 50% to the total size of the Imperial fleet?

---

<sup>1</sup>This isn't as implausible as it might seem - remember that in the actual film, Han says Alderaan's destruction would have required "a thousand ships".

Comment: Are you sure that he's not referring to the death star's 'turbo lasers' rather than the primary weapon?

Comment: @Richard - It certainly doesn't sound like that's what he means.  Consider Han's statement in the movie - blowing up Alderaan would take "a thousand ships and more firepower than I've..."  They both seem to be talking about overall firepower.

Comment: Well, excuse me for being blunt... but Han is a doofus. He's obviously *wrong* with his assessment, since as we've seen, Alderaan *was* destroyed. In fact, it was destroyed with such overwhelming force that the planet dispersed at an incredible speed, a massive overkill *if* that wasn't absolutely necessary to penetrate any planetary shielding available. The main reason for the superlaser was the ability to pierce planetary shields, not destroying planets. Just the dinky Hoth shield was strong enough to prevent planetary bombardment in ESB - Alderaans was probably a whole different league.

Comment: You would have to compare it to other technologies that could blow up planets and decide which gives you more bang for the buck, so what alternatives do you want it to be compared to?

Comment: [No, it is not cost effective](https://petitions.whitehouse.gov/response/isnt-petition-response-youre-looking)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm its more than 'not cost effective' - it was an [economic poison pill](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.09054) in the event that the Empire was overturned.

Comment: @PlasmaHH  - As the question says, I want it to be compared to Star Destroyers.

Comment: @WadCheber: That is comparing like planes and huge trucks. In some universe the later might be cheaper but still can not fly to another continent. The death stars purpose was to destroy planets and it was build for that, so in terms of cost efficience you need to compare it to something that can destroy planets too

Comment: @PlasmaHH - **This comparison is made in the novelization AND the movie itself!**

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Did you even read the question?  Or watch the movie and hear Han say that it would take a thousand ships to blow up Alderaan?

Comment: I'm assuming this questions is primarily asking about the first Death Star. Considering that it was destroyed after firing only once, and considering that the Rebellion fleet that destroyed it was fairly small and presumably *much* less expensive (a few dozen bombers and fighter-bombers), then the answer is no. It was not very cost effective, mainly because it wasn't particularly effective and could be destroyed in an *extremely* cost effective way. But... I don't think this is an earth shattering revelation, nor what you're actually trying to ask.

Comment: "Additionally, we will assume that half the Imperial fleet firing on a planet would have the same effect as the Death Star firing on the planet." This is a major assumption that is, imo, completely unwarranted. Until we have a fairly solid answer to that, the question seems mostly speculative to me. Additionally, Dodonna could simply be referring to raw energy output (Joules or megatons, for instance) for all we know. For comparison, I'm pretty sure the equivalent amount of TNT wouldn't have the same effect as an atomic bomb.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I would have agreed with you, but Han specifically says, in the movie, that destroying Alderaan would require "a thousand ships".  This is clearly a statement of equal effect via different means.  In any case, I'm not necessarily saying it is true, I'm saying "let's assume we can take these statements at face value".

Comment: It sounds more to me like he is stressed and confused over the fact that they've landed in a massive asteroid field instead of at Alderaan, despite trusting his capabilities as a pilot. He isn't quite sure what's going on, and he blurts out the first comparison that comes to mind to emphasize how ridiculous the idea of Alderaan getting blown up is. It is a hyperbole or some other similar literary device, not to be taken as an actual calculation.

Comment: @jpmc26 - And yet it isn't unduly presumptuous to take it at face value for the sake of argument.  That's all I am doing.  Not to mention that Dodonna's figures are in the ballpark of Han's (1,000 vs. 12.5k [the latter number is from the answer below]), but still significantly higher.

Comment: @Luaan Regarding the planetary shielding it is reasonable to assume that Alderaan never raised its planetary shields. As far as (most?) anyone on the planet was concerned Alderaan was a peaceful law abiding member of the empire.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Your math is off - the exchange you need to talk about is the destruction of Alderaan in the first battle vs the Station in the second for trifling losses.  In terms of numbers of people, and value of material destroyed overall the exchange rate is massively in favor of death star #1.

Comment: @Oldcat: The destruction of Alderaan was a battle? I guess I missed the part where the Rebels attempted to defend Alderaan from the Death Star. Unless [Alderaan shot first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQyd9tEDhSc). However, I'm not sure it matters. If you assume that the Empire could already destroy planets with thousands of ships, like this question assumes (quoting Han Solo), then Alderaan's destruction is less of a factor. But, I question just how "destroyed" thousands of Star Destroyers could render a planet compared to the Death Star, so I understand your point and somewhat agree.

Comment: @Ellesedil - I quote Han in comments, not the question.  The question quotes the general of the Rebel Alliance.

Comment: @Ellesedil - Results without battles are still results.  Why would you assume that regular ships could destroy a planet? It is pretty much canonthat this feature is unique to the Death Stars...hence the name.  If not, why aren't the rebels plastering the Imperial Capital?

Comment: WadCheber: Actually, when I brought up the scene in question to respond to @Oldcat, Han explicitly says that ["The entire star fleet couldn't destroy the whole planet, it'd take a thousand ships with more power than I've-"](https://youtu.be/JGp_5gOww0E?t=18s). So I'm not sure your footnote is really applicable.

Comment: @Oldcat: However, [Genera Dodonna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEOAKZ3CFIU) *does* say that the Death Star has the firepower of over half the star fleet. This suggests the Empire could already destroy planets if they concentrated their fleet, which is the basis of this question. I'm willing to take the good General at his word, since I'd consider him to be an expert due to experience and having analyzed the Death Star plans.

Comment: @ellesedil - we don't know what he was going to say.

Comment: Han said enough for us to know that he finds the possibility that the Empire destroyed Alderaan impossible *in the moment*. It turns out that a more reputable source later in the movie contradicts Han's statement, so Han seems to be wrong.

Comment: @Xantec It would be reasonable to assume, but ILM did their job - the planetary shield is *visible* when struck by the superlaser, and it even *blocks* the superlaser for a split-second (about one frame of video), further cementing the mind-blowing strength of planetary shields in the SW universe. Maybe the superlaser could be tenth of the strength it is, but definitely not a hundredth - that would likely not be able to penetrate the shield at all.

Comment: @WadCheber Also note that even the "half the imperial fleet" figure doesn't mean the equivalent of 12,500 ISDs (all of the 25,000 were built in the 20 years between the fall of the republic and ANH). ISDs certainly aren't the biggest part of the fleet, and they aren't even the biggest *ships*, nor the most expensive. You can use the figure as a lower estimate, not as a higher estimate. A big motivating factor in their development was *terror* - if you see an ISD in orbit of your planet, you're going to have to change your underwear.

Comment: @Luaan It is impossible to say what the impact of the Death Star weapon hitting a planet looks like, whether the planet is shield or unshielded, as the weapon had never been used on a planet before. Thus whatever ILM put in the movie or the SE could be anything. While the novelization may indicate that Alderaan is as well defended as any other planet (sans weapons per Leia), there is no affirmation that a shield was activated.

Comment: @Xantec There's no explicit operation procedure I know of that would say if shields are always-on or not, but given the speeds of ships in the SW universe, it seems ridiculous that they would ever be offline. Remember, when the Falcon was lost from imperial sensors in ESB, their initial reaction was "Invisibility or hyperspace" - the ships are so fast that they leave sensor range in such a short time that it's possible to *miss them entirely*. The same would apply for approaching a planet - they might not have enough time to power up the shield with minutes of warning, much less seconds.

Comment: @Ellesedil While Dodonna does say that, it's not clear whether he included the super-laser in that estimate. I'm more inclined to believe that it was included, since no Rebel capital ships were present at Yavin - so turbolasers would be just a useless bit of trivia. They were attacking DS because of the super-laser, not because it's a formidable battle-station even without it. Of course, it doesn't tell us much about the rest of the fleet, since we have no idea how many *other* super-lasers and similar ultra-high-yield weapons are part of the fleet (DS just has the biggest super-laser).

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Dead link, but it's archived at https://petitions.obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/petition/secure-resources-and-funding-and-begin-construction-death-star-2016

Answer (score 36, accepted):

An answer can certainly be calculated, but it requires the use of numbers from both canon and Legends, as not all statistics found in Legends material have an equivalent figure accounted for in Disney canon.

First, the figures (canon unless stated otherwise):

- [Death Star I](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station): over 1 trillion credits (1.5 tn in Legends)
- [Death Star II](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_II): over 1 trillion credits (unknown in Legends)
- [Imperial I-Class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial-class_Star_Destroyer): Unknown
- [Imperial II-Class Star Destroyer](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_II-class_Star_Destroyer/Legends): 145,670,000 credits in Legends

All figures are based on the value of the Imperial credit in 0 BBY. **Skip to the bottom for the final math**.

Some historical background on each of the above to set the context for comparison:

- The DS-I is the first of its kind. Start-up costs are high as most of the DS-I's budget goes heavily into R&D of completely new technology and infrastructure set-up. These are sunk costs.
- The DS-II, though much bigger and contains more technical features than the DS-I, is ultimately just an upgrade of what already exists. Much of what is already developed for the construction of the DS-I, paid for in the sunk costs, can be reused, so that component need not be paid for again beyond maintenance costs. However, this "savings" is countered by a major scaling up of the DS-II compared to the DS-I: Larger battlestation, more surface defences, more advanced superlaser, more hangars and on-board TIE squadrons etc. all of which costs more money. This is probably why the DS-I and DS-II may have similar costs.
- The Imperial I-Class Star Destroyer was developed to replace the Venator-Class Star Destroyer and would become the symbol of the Imperial Navy. At the height of the Empire (presumed 0 BBY), there are over 25,000 ISDs in the galaxy.
- The Imperial II-Class Star Destroyer is an upgrade to the Imperial I-Class and the first completed ships entered service in 0 BBY. They are present at both the Battle of Hoth and the Battle of Endor.

In business, the one-off sunk costs into inventing the product and setting up the production line doesn't factor into the price tag - the long-term fixed and variable costs, and the desired profit margin determines the price tag, and the amount of profits earned determines the breakeven point when the initial investment is fully repaid.

As such, I will answer your question using the following interpretation: **What is the opportunity cost of building the Death Star II compared to building more Imperial II-Class Star Destroyers?** In 0 ABY, Emperor Palpatine would have to choose between building the DS-II to replace the DS-I, or expand the Imperial Navy even further with the same amount of funds instead. The sunk costs for both are largely paid for already, so the only expenditure is into actual production of the next order. These are the numbers that would be presented to him:

Assuming the DS-II costs exactly 1 trillion credits, then given that the Imperial II-Class Star Destroyer costs 145,670,000 credits, **the DS-II would be the financial equivalent of 6,864.83 Imperial Star Destroyers**. Assuming the current fleet has 25,000 ISDs, the opportunity cost of building the Death Star II would be expanding the Imperial fleet by a further **27.46%**.

**Disclaimer**: This estimate assumes the DS-II at the cheapest possible price, and the entire Imperial starfleet as composing of only ISDs. The actual price of the DS-II would raise the estimate, but including the rest of the Imperial Starfleet (any assault ship not ISD: Acclamators and Venators still in service, Victory-Class, Interdictors, Super Star Destroyers, non-Star Destroyers etc.) will lower the estimate.

Comment: Brilliant answer.  +1 and expect a bounty.

Comment: Reflecting on this, you can see that in terms of raw firepower, the Death Stars are incredibly worth it. The DS-II costs up to a quarter of the entire Imperial fleet, and the DS-I even less if you exclude the sunk cost. If the DS-I is really equivalent to half the Imperial fleet in firepower, and we know the DS-II is about 3 times that, then you're getting over 6 times as much bang for your buck. Of course, what the ISDs lack in literal-bang-for-your-buck, they make up for it in tactical and strategic value.

Comment: But if Han was correct when he said blowing up Alderaan would only take 1,000 ships, then the DS was less cost effective.

Comment: I would argue he meant it figuratively - he's a born smuggler in canon and a former stormtrooper at best in Legends. He may know how many Star Destroyers it takes to render a planet inhospitable with orbital bombardment, but nobody has actually destroyed a planet before, much less teach planetary destruction physics in the Imperial Academy (Han would probably fail that class anyway). There hasn't been superweapons in the galaxy since the war before the founding of the Galactic Republic. Basically, Han doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: Well, in legends, Malak destroyed Taris, but otherwise you're right.

Comment: @WadCheber he didn't destroy the planet, just raised he city to the ground.

Comment: The planet was a city.  Destroying the city means destroying the surface of the planet, basically.

Comment: Come to think of it: 1,000 ships is quite a small number. If the equivalent of 1,000 ISDs bombarding a planet from all sides can destroy it, criminal empires the like of Black Sun and the Hutts would have held the military-less Galactic Republic to ransom long ago.

Comment: @WadCheber Destroying the surface isn't destroying the whole thing. All orbital bombardments can destroy the surface of a planet, but you won't call the planet destroyed

Comment: @WadCheber In particular, in Legends, we actually *know* how many ISDs it takes to "level" a planet - the number is *three*. This turns a few meters of the surface to *glass*, and is still fast enough to prevent any escaping vessels - it's actually a *standard imperial procedure*. Needless to say, it only works on planets without planetary shields (in one mentioned case, the shields were taken offline by saboteurs). Han simply blurted out a "huge" number without really thinking about it. Would you expect he'd actually *know* the real number? R2D2 might, but not Han.

Comment: @Luaan why 3? Is that the number you need hitting a single area to render it inhospitable?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Time and coverage is the constraint. The operation is designed to prevent anyone from leaving the planet in question while you perform the bombardment. Star Destroyers *are* powerful enough to destroy anything unshielded quite easily, but they can't shoot *through* a planet. In the cases we've read about, there were literally no survivors - not even one personal starship slipped through. Unless you chalk it up to ignorance on part of the writers (but they, why three ships? :)), that's pretty impressive for a universe where starships are about as common as cars.

Comment: @Luaan So, am I right to say this: One ISD bombards the planet, two provides support in covering both sides of the planet, and their combined three fleets of TIEs and any gun unused in the bombardment is used to lock down escaping ships from jumping to hyperspace and slowly picking them off?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Yeah, that's how I see it too. Though they are probably *all* firing, prioritizing ground targets like spaceports to limit the amounts of spaceborne targets they have to care of - a single blast from a heavy turbolaser would probably be capable of taking care of the whole spaceport (at least temporarily) strainding or destroying multiple ships at the same time (and usually those would be powered off, with no shielding).

Comment: "At the height of the Empire (presumed 0 BBY), there are over 25,000 ISDs in the galaxy." Is there a source for this number? I don't dispute it, but I would like to verify it.

Comment: @Ellesedil http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial-class_Star_Destroyer cites Star Wars: Uprising as the canon source.